# How to trigger password reset without a notification in Laravel Breeze?

Tags: laravel, forgot-password, laravel-mail, laravel-breeze

Using Laravel 9 with Breeze I want when a user with a specific role has been created, he should receive a custom welcome mail with a link to a view, where he needs to set a password

How can I just trigger the password reset without the default forgot password mail, but get the token that I can use in my custom mail for the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a random string of 35 characters.

Create an entry in the password_resets table comprising the user's email address, a hashed (`bcrypt()`) version of the token just created, and the current timestamp

Send the user an email with a link leading to /reset-password/{$token}

Example, assuming $user is the new user account;

```
$token = Str::random(35);

DB::table('password_resets')->insert([
    'email' => $user->email,
    'token' => bcrypt($token),
    'created_at' => now(), 
]);

$user->notify(new WelcomeNewUser($token));
```

and then in the notification class;

```
    public $token;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

//

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('You have been invited to use our application')
                    ->action('Set a password', url(route('password.reset',['token'=>$this->token])))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
```